# Why RequireJS truncates '.js' from the main module name and cannot find the file afterwards?

Tags: playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.1

This happened to me while using the Play! framework, but I think it could happen generally when using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

In t he template I have used the statement:

```
 <script>require = {
      // The path where your JavaScripts are located
      baseUrl: "assets/js/",
    ...
};</script>
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("js/require-jquery.js").url, module = routes.Assets.at("js/main.js").url)
```

Which is compiled to:

```
<script> require = ... </script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/assets/js/main.js" src="/assets/js/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

When I hit reload in the browse I can see the following errors in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/assets/js/main?bust=1361232944505 404 (Not Found) require-jquery.js:1843
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

As you can see the file requested has the extension `.js` truncated. Why? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the RequireJS config contains the `baseUrl` field, and the same path is repeated in the `data-main` attribute of the `script` tag. Changing the Play! framework helper statement to:

```
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("js/require-jquery.js").url, module = "main")
```

or in general case:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="main" src="/assets/js/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

removes the problem.

Why that happens and manifests that vague way is the question to the RequireJS developers. Anyway the Play! framework sample described in the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/RequireJS-support) or [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/RequireJS-support) should be corrected, and the [common errors section on the RequireJS page](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html) should also be updated.